# How to remove any whitespace from user input in read command

Tags: bash, shell

I just started learning bash, and I'm trying to write a very basic bash script that asks a question answerable by yes or no but should remove any white space if the user enters multiple characters. I tried using `tr` and `xargs` but I keep getting a subshell issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=1
while [ $x -le 1 ]
 do
  read -r -p "Are you good? (y/n): " good | tr -d '[:blank:]'

  if [ "${good,,}" == "y" ]; then
  echo "Nice!"
  ((x++))
  break
  elif [ "${good,,}" == "n" ]; then
  echo "That's ok"
  ((x++))
  else 
  echo "Only answer with y or n (ctrl+c to exit)"
  fi
done
```

I'm getting this error on the "read" line:

```
Modification of good is local (to subshell caused by pipeline)
```

and this on the "if" and "elif" lines:

```
good was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.
```

I tried the pipeline xards, tr, sed, awk, etc. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Piping `read` to `tr` does not do what you want. Simply read the user input in the `good` variable (no pipe), and then use bash pattern substitution to remove all spaces: `good="${good// }"`.

Comment: [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) is relevant. (BTW, you're not getting _errors_, you're getting _linter warnings_... but they're accurate and useful warnings in this case, and they're telling you exactly what's wrong).

Comment: And as Renaud says, the correct answer to this is _don't_. Could we come up with some kind of abomination that first uses `read` and then pipes its output somewhere? Sure -- `good=$(read -r good && { printf '%s\n' "$good" | tr -d '[[:space:]]'; })` technically works, but in every practical respect it's _worse_ than just following the advice Renaud gives above, of using two separate commands, as in `read -r good; good=${good//[[:space:]]/}`.

Comment: Remember, pipes connect one command's stdout to another command's stdin, and `read` writes nothing at all to stdout -- so piping from it will never do anything useful.

Comment: Thanks, Renaud! Thanks, Charles! The pattern Renaud gave produces the output I want and your explanation helped me understand it better.